# update particular single subdocument in nested array in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to nodejs and mongo db. I have nested subdocument type schema in mongo. Document type is Process => Subprocess => tasks => configs. These are in the format of nested arrays and can be multiple.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bcec0ee711fe511f4848c1d"),
    "process_title" : "customer acquisition",
    "subprocess" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bcec0f8711fe511f4848c1e"),
            "subprocess_title" : "application",
            "tasks" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5bcec158711fe511f4848c1f"),
                    "task_title" : "pre screening",
                    "task_slug" : "pre-screening",
                    "task_configs" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bcec4b912582b01b84fe47a"),
                            "next_task" : "thanks"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5bcec190711fe511f4848c20"),
                    "task_title" : "thanks",
                    "task_slug" : "thanks",                       
                    "task_configs" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bcec469ab23ab1fc0bbb9ed"),
                            "form_field" : "responseMessage",
                            "expression" : "=",
                            "expression_value" : "Approved4",
                            "success_task" : "signup",
                            "success_sub_process_id" : "5bcec0f8711fe511f4848c1e",
                            "fail_task" : "thanks",
                            "fail_sub_process_id" : "5bcec0f8711fe511f4848c1e"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5bcec1c3711fe511f4848c21"),
                    "task_title" : "signup",
                    "task_slug" : "signup",                        

                    "task_configs" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bcec469ab23ab1fc0bbb9ed"),
                            "form_field" : "responseMessage",
                            "expression" : "=",
                            "expression_value" : "Approved4",
                            "success_task" : "signup",
                            "success_sub_process_id" : "5bcec0f8711fe511f4848c1e",
                            "fail_task" : "thanks",
                            "fail_sub_process_id" : "5bcec0f8711fe511f4848c1e"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-10-23T06:34:22.676Z"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2018-10-23T06:34:22.676Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now I want to update task_configs for a particular task. I am updating task_config on the basis of task_slug.

Comment: Do you need to update entire task config, or only a particular field in it? If multiple task congig in task array, do you need to update all of them? Give an example.

Comment: Yes, I need to update the entire task config for a particular task. If there is multiple task config array then when I submit the form then this new task config array will be updated by a new one.

Comment: db.workflows.update({
    "subprocess.tasks.task_slug": "signup"
  },
  {"$set": {"subprocess.$[].tasks.$.task_configs": [{"expression": "321"}] }}
)

Answer (score 0):

```
I found a  way myself to update above query.

Workflow.updateOne({ "_id": new ObjectId(req.body.process_id), "subprocess._id": new ObjectId(req.body.sub_process_id), "subprocess.tasks.task_slug": req.body.task_slug },
    {
      $set: {
        'subprocess.$.tasks.$[j].task_configs': req.body.task_configs
      }
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          "j.task_configs": req.body.task_configs
        }]
    })
    .then(function (resp) {
      console.log(resp)
      res.json({ status: 'success', resp });
    }).catch(function (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    })
```